# Django, Dash App Safest Place to Keep Database Credentials

Tags: django, sqlalchemy, plotly-dash, pymysql

I'm new to web development. I have a Django project that loads a Dash app on one of it's pages. The dash app generates a chart that lets the user select certain datasets from the database.

Directly inside my App.py (dash app) I placed my sqlalchemy database connection variables which one of the callbacks uses to fetch the data when requested.

```
sqlEngine = sa.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://host:password@127.0.0.1:3306/db', pool_recycle=3600)
dbConnection = sqlEngine.connect()
conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',user='host',password='password',db='db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

app = DjangoDash(name='app', add_bootstrap_links=True, serve_locally = False)

...

@app.callback(...)
def fetch_data(...):
    select = """SELECT * FROM `db`.`table`;"""
    df = pd.read_sql(select, dbConnection)
```

I'm not sure if this is a safe practice in a production environment. What would be the best/safest way to  connect to the database inside of the dash app.

My Django app is also connected to the database for migrations. Thanks for any help/advice.

Answer (score 0):

In [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/deployment/checklist/#secret-key) it says that you shouldn't commit your secret key, so you can keep it in a separate file and read it from there. [Again in documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/#databases) it says you should treat the database credentials the same way. So I suggest you to keep them in a file and read it from there, not by importing but by using open as they do in the documentation, or set it as an environment variable.